# Final inesperado en getLocalHost con InetAddress

Tags: java

Necesito conectarme a un equipo usando RMI, pero la clase servidor del proyecto tiene la siguiente línea:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().toString()
```

De la cual según la documentación espero me retorne un `String` con la dirección de red de mi máquina, estoy conectado a una red y esperaría una IP diferente a `localhost`, sin embargo este método retorna `127.0.1.1`.

Aquí tengo el código del [proyecto](https://github.com/Emanuel971022/ageCalculatorRMI/blob/master/src/controller/ageServer.java#L23).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que el problema son las interfaces de red. En mi máquina yo tengo `eth0` y `lo`:

```
$ ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 34:17:eb:d8:9e:83  
          inet addr:10.91.11.30  Bcast:10.91.11.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3617:ebff:fed8:9e83/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12685226 errors:0 dropped:321209 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6092251 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6504196254 (6.5 GB)  TX bytes:1019289759 (1.0 GB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:587126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:587126 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:259789919 (259.7 MB)  TX bytes:259789919 (259.7 MB)
```

Si ejecuto el siguiente código:

```
import java.net.*;

public class Address {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            InetAddress IP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            System.out.println("Mi IP es: " + IP.getHostAddress());
        } catch( UnknownHostException e ) {
          System.out.println(e);
        }   
    }    
}
```

El resultado es:

```
$ java Address
Mi IP es: 127.0.1.1
```

Y eso está bastante lejos de lo que buscas. Sin embargo si iteramos las interfaces e imprimos las direcciones IP podemos acercarnos más:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Address {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            System.out.println("------------------");
            while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface interfaz = interfaces.nextElement();
                System.out.println("Interfaz: " + interfaz.getDisplayName());
                Enumeration<InetAddress> direccion = interfaz.getInetAddresses();
                while (direccion.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress ip = direccion.nextElement();
                    System.out.println(ip.getHostAddress());
                }
                System.out.println("------------------");
            }
        } catch(SocketException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

El resultado de el código anterior sería:

```
$ java Address
------------------
Interfaz: eth0
fe80:0:0:0:3617:ebff:fed8:9e83%2
10.91.11.30
------------------
Interfaz: lo
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1
127.0.0.1
------------------
```

Ya tenemos las interfaces, y las direcciones IPv4 e IPv6 de cada interfaz.

Incluso podrías deshacerte del [Loopback](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) usando el método [`isLoopback`](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#isLoopback()) de la interfaz:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Address {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            System.out.println("------------------");
            while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface interfaz = interfaces.nextElement();
                // No necesitamos el Loopback
                if (interfaz.isLoopback()) {
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println("Interfaz: " + interfaz.getDisplayName());
                Enumeration<InetAddress> direccion = interfaz.getInetAddresses();
                while (direccion.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress ip = direccion.nextElement();
                    System.out.println(ip.getHostAddress());
                }
                System.out.println("------------------");
            }
        } catch(SocketException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora el resultado sería:

```
$ java Address 
------------------
Interfaz: eth0
fe80:0:0:0:3617:ebff:fed8:9e83%2
10.91.11.30
------------------
```

Si no necesitas la IPv6, puedes preguntar si la IP en cuestión es de la instancia `Inet6Address`:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Address {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            System.out.println("------------------");
            while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface interfaz = interfaces.nextElement();
                // No necesitamos el Loopback
                if (interfaz.isLoopback()) {
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println("Interfaz: " + interfaz.getDisplayName());
                Enumeration<InetAddress> direccion = interfaz.getInetAddresses();
                while (direccion.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress ip = direccion.nextElement();
                    // Solo IPv4
                    if (ip instanceof Inet6Address) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    System.out.println(ip.getHostAddress());
                }
                System.out.println("------------------");
            }
        } catch(SocketException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Finalmente, el resultado es:

```
$ java Address 
------------------
Interfaz: eth0
10.91.11.30
------------------
```

Bueno, creo que esto ya se acerca bastante a lo que buscas.

### Referencias

- [Class InetAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html)
- [Listing Network Interface Addresses](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/nifs/listing.html)
- [Inet4Address](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html)
- [Inet6Address](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/Inet6Address.html)

Comment: Nota: puedes cambiar el `for(; interfaces.hasMoreElements();)` por `while(interfaces.hasMoreElements())`. Excelente respuesta, por cierto.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza gracias master!

Comment: jaja @LuiggiMendoza el mismo comentario... aqui. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381316/java-inetaddress-getlocalhost-returns-127-0-0-1-how-to-get-real-ip#comment18571357_7334091

Comment: @rnd coincidencias de la vida (:

Comment: @rnd cuando aprendí Java siempre usaba esa forma, siempre me olvidaba del `while`